# Pull a timelines by product by instance into 1 row instead of many

Tags: teradata, teradatasql

I'm trying to pull the timeline for each function into 1 line for each car.
The car started in the factory,
Function - Start Date - End Date - Person
the frame was built on 05/23/2022 04:16 AM 05/23/2022 06:16 AM By Joe,
the Windshield was installed on 05/23/2022 9:18 PM 05/23/2022 10:18 PM By Suzy,
the Motor was installed on 05/25/2022 01:14 PM 05/25/2022 03:23 PM By Harry,
the Frame was Painted on 05/28/2022 9:45 PM 05/29/2022 9:45 PM by Joe.

for each car I want to take the individual records above and join into 1 row to show the timelines for this 1 card, which eventually will lead to help me find my bottle necks and processing time.
I'm trying to build two different sets of data. 1 how mayne windshields did joe do and whats joes downtime in between each windsheild, how long did it take us to build the car, which i can do some datediffs, but trying to get each car on 1 line form the different entry's.
i'm thinking i have to do some Lead / Lag.
Thinking my data would be 1 line:

Model T1 - frame - 05/23/2022 04:16 AM 05/23/2022 06:16 AM - Joe - Windsheild - 05/23/2022 9:18 PM - 05/23/2022 10:18 PM - Suzy - Motor Installed - 5/25/2022 01:14 PM - 05/25/2022 03:23 PM - Harry - Frame Painted 05/28/2022 9:45  - PM 05/29/2022 9:45 - Joe Total Time to Assemble 5:16 HH: MM
`Select Insert DateTime as Production Start DateTime, StartDate as StartDate, Min(StartDate) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO, StartDate ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO, StartDate DESC) AS FrameBuilt, Lag(StartDate) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO, StartDate DESC) AS WindsheildInstalled, Lead(EndDate) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate DESC) AS WindsheildInstalledStarted, EndDate as WindsheildInstallCompleted,  Lag(EndDate) Over (PARTITION BY ASSIGNEDTO ORDER BY ASSIGNEDTO, EndDate DESC) AS MotorInstalled, CASE WHEN Cast(ENDDATE AS DATE) + 1 = Cast(Lag_next_start AS DATE) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS flag, Case when Cast(EndDate as Date) = Cast(Startdate as Date) then 1 Else 0 End as count2, Case When EndDate = StartDate then 1 Else 0 End as count1,TaskName, (max_start - min_start) Hour(4) TO SECOND as htm, (max_start - min_start) Hour(4) TO SECOND as tbt,(tbt = Time between Task) From WorkflowLog as wfl left join functions_FILTERED as pdf on wfl.INTERNALID = pdf.INTERNALID QUALIFY (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY wfl.INTERNALID ORDER BY STARTDATE DESC))=1) as a`

Comment: Can you format your question, try to add the data in tabular format. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post

Comment: `| LID | ASSIGNEDTO |11 AUDITDATETIME |10 STARTDATE |9 ENDDATE |8 TASKNAME |7 Function |6 NUMBER |5 PRODUCT |4 TYPE |3 PRIORITY |2 TYPE2 |2 <br/>
| 52116 | Joem | 5/10/22 12:00 AM | 5/10/22 11:29 AM | 5/10/22 11:29 AM | Initial Review | Motor Install | A2213196882 | Ford | F150 | Standard | 5 Speed | <br/>
| 52118 | Joem | 5/11/22 12:00 AM | 5/11/22 11:20 AM | 5/11/22 3:09 PM | Initial Review | Motor Install | A2213181875 | Ford | F150 | Standard | 5 Speed | <br/>'

![Valid XHTML]
`

Comment: ![Valid XHTML](https://w3.org/Icons/valid-xhtml10).

Comment: for me its taking all the task and their end times and adding them to one row.